# TypeError: get_first_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in Python

Tags: python

So im having trouble displaying the admins first name, for some reason it keeps saying it doesnt exist, please give me some feedback on whats wrong, very appreciated
below you can find the admin class where we set all parameters like first name and last name etc
after that weve got the bank system class where ive imported the admin class and instanced it and still nothing, **even after adding the missing positional argument it says that fname does not exist**

```
class Admin:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, address, user_name, password, full_rights):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.address = address
        self.user_name = user_name 
        self.password = password
        self.full_admin_rights = full_rights

    def update_first_name(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def update_last_name(self, lname):
        self.lname = lname

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.fname

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.lname
```

```
from customer_account import CustomerAccount
from admin import Admin

accounts_list = []
admins_list = []

class BankSystem(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts_list = []
        self.admins_list = []
        self.load_bank_data()

    def load_bank_data(self):

        # create admins
        admin_1 = Admin("Julian", "Padget", ["12", "London Road", "Birmingham", "B95 7TT"], "id1188", "1441", True)
        self.admins_list.append(admin_1)

        admin_2 = Admin("Cathy",  "Newman", ["47", "Mars Street", "Newcastle", "NE12 6TZ"], "id3313", "2442", False)
        self.admins_list.append(admin_2)


    def search_admins_by_name(self, admin_username):
        found_admin =None
        for a in self.admins_list:
            username =a.get_username()
            if username ==admin_username:
                found_admin =a
                break
        if found_admin ==None:
            print("\n The Admin %s does not exist! Try again...\n"%admin_username)

        return found_admin


    def main_menu(self):
        #print the options you have
        print()
        print()
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print ("Welcome to the Python Bank System")
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print ("1) Admin login")
        print ("2) Quit Python Bank System")
        print (" ")
        option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
        return option


    def run_main_options(self):
        loop = 1         
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.main_menu()
            if choice == 1:
                username = input ("\n Please input admin username: ")
                password = input ("\n Please input admin password: ")
                admin_obj = self.admin_login(username, password)

                if admin_obj != None:
                    self.run_admin_options(admin_obj)
            elif choice == 2:
                loop = 0
        print ("\n Thank-You for stopping by the bank!")

    def admin_login(self, username, password):
        found_admin=self.search_admins_by_name(username)
        msg="\n Login failed"
        if found_admin!=None:
                if found_admin.get_password()==password:
                    print("Login Sucssesful")
        return msg,found_admin

    def admin_menu(self, admin_obj):
        #print the options you have
         admin_obj = Admin
         print (" ")
         print ("Welcome Admin %s %s : Avilable options are:" %(admin_obj.get_first_name(), admin_obj.get_last_name()))
         print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
         print ("1) Transfer money")
         print ("2) Customer account operations & profile settings")
         print ("3) Delete customer")
         print ("4) Print all customers detail")
         print ("5) Sign out")
         print (" ")
         option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
         return option

app = BankSystem()
app.run_main_options()
```

Comment: In `BankSystem.admin_menu`: `admin_obj = Admin` - that's an alias for the `Admin` class, not an _instance_ of the `Admin` class

Comment: That's a lot of code to show your problem. To make it easier for people to help you, try reducing the amount of code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two problems:

1. `BankSystem.admin_login()` returns a pair consisting of a message and an admin object, but `run_main_options()` assigns that pair to a single variable `admin_obj`. You should change it to something like `msg, admin_obj = …` to behave like you appear to expect.
2. `BankSystem.admin_menu()` overwrites the object it was passed on the first line. This line should be removed.

Comment: @Krazzy you're welcome, don't forget to mark as answered if your problem is solved ;-)